# How to combine and add based on category?

Tags: sql, database

For example, I have a table that contains the following:

```
Product Name         Quantity       Category

Mechanical Pencil       3           Stationary
Lead                    4           Stationary
Sherlock Holmes         2           Book
Great Gatsby            2           Book
Paint Brush             1           Art Supplies
Acrylic Paint           5           Art Supplies
```

I want to make the categories in the column header then add the number of quantities based on it like:

```
Stationary         Books         Art Supplies
     7               4                6
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of examples on the web for aggregating numbers in a table. Unfortunately the question currently reads as "write code for me." Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do this by putting the values on separate rows in the result set:

```
select category, sum(quantity)
from t
group by category;
```

That is more flexible, because new rows are added for new categories.

You can do what you want.  One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when category = 'Stationary' then quantity else 0 end) as Stationary,
       sum(case when category = 'Books' then quantity else 0 end) as Books,
       sum(case when category = 'Art Supplies' then quantity else 0 end) as ArtSupplies
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot

```
select * from ( select quantity, category from #yourproducts ) c
pivot(sum(Quantity) for category in ([Stationary],[Book],[Art Supplies])) p
```

Your input table:

```
create table #yourproducts ([Prodcut Name] varchar(20), quantity int, Category varchar(20))

insert into #yourproducts ([Prodcut Name], quantity, Category ) values
 ('Mechanical Pencil',       3      ,'Stationary')
,('Lead             ',       4      ,'Stationary')
,('Sherlock Holmes  ',       2      ,'Book')
,('Great Gatsby     ',       2      ,'Book')
,('Paint Brush      ',       1      ,'Art Supplies')
,('Acrylic Paint    ',       5      ,'Art Supplies')
```